# Read XML File with DOMDocument in php

Tags: php, xml, dom

I want to read this xml document:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:getPDMNumber xmlns:tns="http://www.testgroup.com/TestPDM" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.testgroup.com/TestPDM getPDMNumber.xsd ">
  <tns:getPDMNumberResponse>
    <tns:requestID>22222</tns:requestID>
    <tns:pdmNumber>654321</tns:pdmNumber>
    <tns:responseCode>0</tns:responseCode>
  </tns:getPDMNumberResponse>
</tns:getPDMNumber>
```

I tried it this way:

```
$dom->load('response/17_getPDMNumberResponse.xml'); 

$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName("tns:requestID");
//$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName("tns:getPDMNumber");
//$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName("tns:getPDMNumberResponse");
foreach($nodes as $node)
{       
    $response=$node->getElementsByTagName("tns:getPDMNumber");
    foreach($response as $info)
    {
        $test = $info->getElementsByTagName("tns:pdmNumber");
        $pdm = $test->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

the code never runs into the foreach loop.

Only for clarification my goal is to read the "tns:pdmNumber" node.

Have anybody a idea?

EDIT: I have also tried the commited lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML uses a namespace, so you should use the namespace aware methods. They have the suffix `_NS`.

```
$tns = 'http://www.testgroup.com/TestPDM';
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
foreach ($document->getElementsByTagNameNS($tns, "pdmNumber") as $node) {
  var_dump($node->textContent);
}
```

Output:

```
string(6) "654321"
```

A better option is to use Xpath expression. They allow a more comfortable access to DOM nodes. In this case you have to register a prefix for the namespace that you can use in the Xpath expression:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('t', 'http://www.testgroup.com/TestPDM');

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(/t:getPDMNumber/t:getPDMNumberResponse/t:pdmNumber)')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName("tns:requestID");
```

you find all the `requestID` nodes, and try to loop on them. That's fine, but then you use that node as a basis to find any `getPDMNumber` nodes **UNDER** the `requestID` - but there's nothing - requestID is a terminal node. So

```
$response=$node->getElementsByTagName("tns:getPDMNumber");
```

finds nothing, and the inner loop has nothing to do.

It's like saying "Start digging a hole until you reach china. Once you reach China, keep digging until you reach Australia". But you can't keep digging - you've reached the "bottom", and the only thing deeper than China would be going into orbit.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Please look at my edit section above.